# Application is closing after upgrading to 2.0

Tags: leakcanary

I've upgraded from 1.x to LeakCanary 2.0-alpha-3, and now, couple of sesonds after start, my app closes itself, and LeakCanary notification appears.

This renders my app unusable. Why is that, and what can I do with that?

There is nothing interesting in logcat.

All the leaks it detect are in 3rd party analytical libraries, so I probably can't fix them event if I want. But I'll definitely report them to librarie's authors.

Comment: Can you report your issue here: https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/new/choose ? You'll need to provide more context, e.g. the logs from Logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, find a couse.

Our app uses READ_PHONE_STATE permissions and checks if the app has it, otherwise finishes the activity. And we somehow forgot to put it in our Manifest.xml. And it worked, because LeakCanary 1.x for some reason has this permission in it's Manifest.

2.0 doesn't have this permission in Manifest anymore, so our activity finshed itself. Adding this permission to our Manifest fixed the issue.